# Bash - Get only directory names from git status

Tags: bash, git, shell, directory, git-status

I just need the directory names from the git status. As a short form when I use `git status -s`, I get the following output.

```
M stack/pipeline.yaml
?? stackother/
```

Whereas I just need `stack/` and `stackother/` as a list or just as an output which I can pipe to the next set of commands.

Basically, I need the directories which are newly created or directories in which there are some changes in the files. Is there any way to do it using git?

EDIT:
This question is not a duplicate of the linked question as I actually needed the parent directory of each changed file. The following example demonstrates what is needed and what the linked questions answers:

Given these files:
stack/pipeline.yaml
stack/newstack/master-pipeline.yaml
stack/newstack/test/test11.txt
stack/newstack/test/tester.txt

I need:

```
stack
stack/newstack
stack/newstack/test
```

and not (provided by the answer in the linked question):

```
stack
```

For the basic example, the answer with porcelain worked, but for more changes, I had to perform `git status -s -uall` and work on this output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-status%5D+only+directories

Comment: Updated the question as to why its not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```
git status -s -uall | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 dirname| uniq
```

Comment: I understand what you did here, but somehow there's a space before the M character and it outputs M as an output for the first line, for the second line its good

Comment: What about with `awk '{print $2}'` instead of `cut -d  ' ' -f 2` ?

Comment: git status -s -uall | cut -c 4- | xargs -L1 dirname, this worked for me. Also,  git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 dirname

Please update your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Updated with awk :-)

Comment: Actually, the command with porcelain doesn't fit my need because I needed the parent directory for each file change and for my given example the porcelain answer worked as well. I have updated the question as its been marked as duplicate when its not. 

`git status -s -uall | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 dirname| uniq` does what i need. May be update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @padawin Cool. The command in this comment section worked. But is there a way to list out the main directory only, not the sub-directory?! The uniq command is cool.